# .htaccess is not working in vps hosting

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

what is solution to create a .htaccess file in vps.
I have tried most of the .htaccess file.but it doesnt work in vps.
What is the solution?

here is the code of htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

this is not working in vps.

Comment: Have you checked that any htaccess overrides are being honored? You might want to check httpd.conf to make sure that AllowOverride is set to allow this and that `AccessFileName .htaccess` is set.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons:

1. Make sure that you've activated the module `rewrite` (`a2enmod rewrite`)
2. Check your `httpd.conf` overriding should be allowed. (e.g replace `AllowOverride none` with `AllowOverride all`)

Comment: why this happend in vps.

Comment: I don't know. Who has set up your vps?

Comment: ok thank you very much.this is very useful for me.